# add sensor linker using android cmake

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, android-sensors

I'm developing a c++ plugin to get android sensor data.

when I compile my shared library using android-cmake toolchain I've got a linker error :

error: undefined reference to 'ASensorManager_getInstance'

How can I add the right library (-landroid or -lsensor I guess) to the compilation using android-cmake?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, just add this in your CMakeLists.txt :

set( CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -landroid")

Hope this will be useful for others

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html)() in your [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/sensor-graph/accelerometer/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt#L9), for example

`target_link_libraries(accelerometergraph
                      android
                      GLESv2
                      log)`

In other words, avoid directly changing the underneath LINKER_FLAGS.